# Strange behviour of realm query

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am making an app with users represented as `RealmObject` and when the user logs in I have some code to check if the user already exists or if that user needs to be created based on an id.

```
 public class User extends RealmObject {
     @PrimaryKey
     public String id;

     public User(String id) {
         this.id = id;
     }
```

Code to check if a user exists:

```
public void checkUser(final HashMap<String, String> data) {
    config = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(syncUser, Constants.realmUri)
                    .schemaVersion(0)
                    .build();
    Realm.getInstanceAsync(config, new Realm.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull Realm realm) {
            AuthActivity.this.realm = realm;

            // Check if user already exist
            RealmQuery<User> query = realm.where(User.class);
            query.equalTo("id", data.get("id"));

            // Execute the query
            User u = query.findFirst();
            if (u == null) {
                createUser(data);
                Log.i("RealmHelper", "User did not exist");
            } else {
                if (u.isValid()) {
                    AuthActivity.this.userId = u.id;
                    startActivityMain();
                    Log.i("RealmHelper", "User did exist");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

`Constants.realmUri` equals a string with the ip and port of my server.

Now if the user exist the above code should obviously log that the user did exist. The problem is that I get the correct behaviour but if I create the user, enter the app, close the app and then remove the app data the `checkUser()` method will return that the user did not exist when trying to log in the next time. I suspect that this has something do with local and remote realms and that the realm used in the `checkUser()` method is somehow local rather than remote.

Despite `checkUser()` saying that the user does not exist, the user is visible in Realm Studio and saved in the syncronized database as it has not been changed.

`id` in User is coming from Facebook and the value remains the same which makes this problem even weirder.

Comment: You have a syncUser object being passed into the SyncConfig Builder method, what is that object? Is it static? Or dynamic?

Comment: The object is set in an asynchronous login in the onSuccess method and then the above checkUser is called. It is not static. I don't see how syncUser would be relevant though.

Comment: My thinking is that since the syncUser is dynamic, it is logging in with different info / configurations and is resulting in Realm believing it to be a new 'instance', which is why it is not finding the previous user. I am still using an older version of Realm, so I am not using the SyncConfiguration code.

Comment: I see, that could be it, I will try setting it to static and experiment a bit.

Comment: I found out after some more debugging that the realm is empty which is why is says that the user does not exist.

Comment: The syncUser and SyncConfiguration objects are properly set. Could it have something to do with schema versions when removing app data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by using waitForInitialRemoteData() in the SyncConfiguration. This makes sure the realm is not empty after clearing app data.